# CSV or xls file upload by he user to populate models in django

Tags: django, csv

What is the correct way to allow csv file upload by the user and parse the data from it to populate the django models.How to handle it in a view using a form with file field.

Comment: You'll have to implement some sort of validation to make sure all fields are present in this spreadsheet. You can have a column with "keys", with each row representing the attribute name and another column with the value for that attribute. You'll need to make sure the data matches your model though.

Comment: check [this](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks @alfonso.kim. It looks like the kind of thing i want but I have a doubt regarding django-excel's reliablity during my django project's scalability.